# Callback to getCurrentPosition at all times on Cordova Media

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am using Cordova Media Plugin in an Ionic Angular 2 app. We are utilizing the API to do things like control the volume, skip and go back in the audio 15 seconds etc. We are looking to implement a progress bar but I haven't found any documentation about callbacks for constantly getting the audio track position and where it currently is (need this to control the progress bar). All of the things like volume are easy to do just because we have the touch event to trigger it. Where as with the audio, we need an update as to where the player is. See we have used getCurrentPosition in the controlSeconds function but I don't know how to constantly call in this in Angular.

Does anyone know how to do this/have any documentation on constantly calling back.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';
import { MediaPlugin, MediaObject } from '@ionic-native/media';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
    selector: 'page-story',
    templateUrl: 'story.html',
 })
export class StoryPage {
    story:any;
    isAudioPlaying:boolean=false;
    volume: number;
    audio: any;
    position: number;
    duration: number;
    status: any;


    // constructor
    // --------------------------------------------------------------
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, private media: MediaPlugin) {
        let story = navParams.get('story');
        this.story = story.fields;
        console.log(this.story);

        const file: MediaObject = this.media.create('http:' + this.story.audioFile.fields.file.url, (status) => {
            this.status = status;
            console.log(this.status);
        });

        this.audio = file;
        this.volume = 50;
        this.position = 0;
    }

    controlVolume(event) {
        var sliderValue = 100 - Number.parseInt(event._barR);
        this.audio.setVolume(sliderValue / 100);
    }

    controlProgressBar(event) {
        // console.log('status: ' + this.status);
        // 2 = playing
        // 3 = paused
        // console.log('scroll to: ' + Number.parseInt(event._barR));
        if(this.isAudioPlaying == true ) {
            this.audio.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
                console.log(position);
            });
        }       
    }

    controlAudio(action){
        switch(action) {
            case 'play':
                this.audio.play();
                this.isAudioPlaying = true;
                this.duration = this.audio.getDuration();
                break;
            case 'pause':
                this.audio.pause();
                this.isAudioPlaying = false;
                break;
        }
    }

    controlSeconds(type) {
        this.audio.getCurrentPosition().then((position) => {
            var number = Number.parseInt(position) * 1000;
            switch(type){
                case 'back':
                    console.log(number);
                    this.audio.seekTo(number - 15000);
                    break;
                case 'forward':
                    console.log(number);
                    this.audio.seekTo(number + 15000);
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnChanges(changes) {
        console.log('change detected: ' + changes);
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log('ionViewDidLoad Story Page');
    }
 }
```

This is the code we currently have, and we are wanting the function controlProgressBar to control the ion-range element we have in a view. Like I said, we need a callback that just constantly checks on the time.

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-range min="0" max="100" [(ngModel)]="duration" color="secondary" (ionChange)="controlProgressBar($event)"></ion-range>
 </ion-item>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use interval function in angular to constantly check the current playing time, like shown below. This will check the current time in each second and will update the duration and hence it should reflect the ion-range control position.

```
setInterval(() => {
    this.duration = this.audio.currentTime
  }, 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks - I saw a lot of people doing it this way but I thought it was a bit hacky, but if there's nothing else, then I guess it's the way to go!